# Negating an alternate definition of a limit point

Tags: real-analysis

I know that one way to define $x$ as a limit point of set $A$ is to say that there is some sequence $\{a_n\}$ contained in $A$ which converges to $x$ and $a_n \neq x$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to negate this definition to say $x$ is not a limit point of set $A$. My attempt has been to say:

$x$ is not a limit point of set $A$ if for all sequences $\{a_n\}$ contained in $A$, $a_n \rightarrow x$ implies there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n = x$.

I'm not sure if that's correct, or if there is a better way to say it. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: So by your definition, constant sequences dont converge?

Comment: @badatmath I'm not sure what you mean. My definition is saying that if $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and ${a_n} = c \forall n$ is a constant sequence contained in $A$, we know that $c$ is not a limit point of $A$. I don't think it's saying that $a_n = c$ doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your negation is correct. You can also say

for all sequences $(a_n)$ of elements in  $ A $, $a_n$ does not converge to $ x$ OR there exists $ n \in \Bbb N $ such that
$ a_n=x$.

$$(\forall (a_n)\in A^{\Bbb N})\;$$
$$ \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n\ne x \;or\; (\exists n\in \Bbb N)\;:\; a_n=x$$

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you so much.